# huge traffic from different IPs on my ubuntu vps

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, ddos, ufw, gunicorn

I've change my vps recently, vps provider told me that he has backed up my VPS hdd from previous server and deployed it on the new server and changed just my ip, but now I have a huge traffic and connections from various IPs and variable ports.
What do you suggest me to do ?
OS is ubuntu, firewall is UFW and on, I've closed any unused ports. I've been using Cloud flare's DDOS protection and I changed my IP one more time.
These huge traffic made my network very slow, when I try to reach my website it takes more seconds to open and time of pinging ip has become 3 times more. I've monitoring traffic with Nethogs.
I think they're sending fake tcp syn packets to my server. The problem still remained even after stopping nginx and gunicorn. I can't ssh to my server even if all of my services have been stopped.

Here's a picture of nethogs graph.
[Nethogs log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Bwso.png)
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ask your provider for a new IP. Maybe they gave you one that was previously assigned to a high-traffic (or under-attack) server.

Comment: I did, we change the ip one more time to be sure about not attaking to ip address directly. I'm using cloudflare dns ddos protection so I think no one know my new ip. @ceejayoz

Answer (score 0):

You might want to configure your firewall to block all connections from certain IP addresses. You could also look at TCPWrappers configurations that is located usually in /etc/hosts.allow and /etc/hosts.deny. There is another way to block unwanted traffic using the webserver you are running.

Comment: I tried to block the IP by ufw. but it didn't work. I'm seeing the connections even after blocking their IP. Actually I think they don't attack on my website or web services, I think that they've created just some fake connections to my vps, maybe they are some fake tcp act.

Answer (score 0):

i would like to recommend you to use NGINX for Proxy or Web Server then setting Page Cache for your website and config rate limit for protect HTTP Flood if you want to protect DDOS Attack you can use CSF Firewall because it is easiest

https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-caching-guide/

https://www.nginx.com/blog/rate-limiting-nginx/

https://configserver.com/cp/csf.html

Good Luck ..

Comment: I think they're sending fake tcp syn packets to my server. The problem still remained even after stopping nginx and gunicorn. @Putter.Network

Comment: you can add this config to /etc/sysctl.conf


#prevent sync flood
net.ipv4.netfilter.ip_conntrack_tcp_timeout_syn_recv=45


net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies = 1


net.ipv4.tcp_max_syn_backlog = 3240000



net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter = 1

Comment: that didn't help @Putter.Network